# EFCore Cancellation in async overloads of IDbContextTransaction

Tags: entity-framework-core

I am currently developing something that relies heavily on locking a small table. I came to wonder what's the use of `transaction.RollbackAsync(CancellationToken)` (or analogous `transaction.CommitAsync(CancellationToken)`). Shouldn't a transaction be guaranteed to be rolled back / committed when called for? I don't really see much sense in cancelling such an operation. In a scenario where I acquire a full lock on the table with a transaction using `IsolationLevel.Serializable` and then cancel amid my following operations on the table eventually calling the rollback or commit would end up never being executed once the token already set `IsCancellationRequested` to `true` (or worse throws on cancellation).

So just for understanding, can somebody explain me why they even got that overload? Is it safe to use or does it make any sense to use them? Should I even consider commiting/rolling back a transaction using `await`? I mean the database for sure releases the lock and discards the transaction when disconnecting, but that probably takes longer than cleanly releasing it as intended.